# How to yield children of span tag using BeautifulSoup/MechanicalSoup - selecting drop-down field values

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to complete a form submission on a webpage (http://supermag.jhuapl.edu/mag/?) using MechanicalSoup. Prior to the submission a date must be specified, within the same form, using drop down boxes for start day, month, year, time etc. This can be done with the `set_select()` MechanicalSoup function, but I cannot seem to access the relevant `select` tag for each field.  A small disclaimer; while I have scientific programming experience I am new to HTML and the Python libraries mentioned above.

While I am unsure which library is best to use for selecting the date, I cannot seem to access the relevant `select` tag that is a child element of corresponding `span` tags within the form, with name attributes such as 'start_day', 'start_month'.

I have both the `mechanicalsoup.Form(form)` and `mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(*args, **kwargs)` objects (the latter corresponding to a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object) and have tried:

- Setting the `select` tags with MechanicalSoup's `set_select`
- Finding the relevant `span` tag and using BeautifulSoup to access the elements below (in particular the `select` tags), with the aim of somehow then choosing the value by changing the URL (?)

A snippet of the relevant HTML is shown; note the `div` tags and subsequent `select` tags as children.

The form tag:

```html
<form name="theForm" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;">
```

The relevant span and select tags within form:

```html
<span name="start_time">
  <div>
    <select name="start_day">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>...
    </select>
    <select style="width: 4em;" name="start_month">
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option...
    </select>
  </div>
</span>
```

Code is found below:

```py
# Opening browser and URL
url = "http://supermag.jhuapl.edu/mag/?"
browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open(url)

# Assigning bs4.BeautifulSoup object
html = browser.get_current_page()

# Assigning relevant form
form = browser.select_form('form[name="theForm"]')

# Assign correct span tag for e.g start_time
start_time_span = html.find_all('span')[2]

# Attempt to set start day value - returns
# 'InvalidFormMethod: No select named start_day'
form.set_select({'start_day': 1})

# Attempt to find select tags with bs4
html.find('select', {'start_day': 1})
start_time_span.find('select', {'start_day': 1})

# and eg looking for contents returns empty list
start_time_span.contents
```

I expected to have the `select` tags listed within the bs4 `find()` attempts, or for the mechanicalsoup `set_select()` to access and set the given `select` tag when called on the correct form.

The `span` tag is found within the BeautifulSoup HTML, but does not seem to have any child `select` tags that are present within the source HTML, and are necessary for selecting the date. Calling `set_select()` returns an error saying that the tag cannot be found.

Thank you in advance; this is my first question on StackOverflow and I hope it meets the guidelines sufficiently well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, your code generally looks fine! When I run your python snippet on the HTML you quote here, it does not raise an `InvalidFormMethod` exception. However, when I run it on the URL you provided, I do see that error (because, looking at the source HTML, there is no element with the name `start_day`).

I suspect this is because a specific JavaScript action is generating the HTML that includes a `start_day` field. This is hinted at by the form having an `onsubmit` attribute and no `action`, as well as including a lot of JavaScript files (which may or may not be necessary to interact with the form). Depending on what exactly you want to do with this form, you probably need to use a tool that supports JavaScript, like Selenium (MechanicalSoup does not -- see [this FAQ](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like I'll have to learn a bit more about form submission in HTML and spotting JavaScript! I have a quick hack solution to my problem - inputting the date manually into a string formatted like the URL output by the JavaScript events like so: `http://supermag.jhuapl.edu/mag/?start=2015-01-22T20%3A50%3A30Z&interval=0%3A24%3A00&stations=NAL%2CLYR%2CHOP%2CBJN%2CHRN%2CBBG&tab=download&baseline=all&delta=none"` and opening a MechanicalSoup browser from here. The download button also has a JavaScript event - will I need Selenium here also?

Comment: Instead of forging the URL, you may also use [new_control](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mechanicalsoup.html#mechanicalsoup.Form.new_control) to create controls, a bit like JavaScript does. You can almost always simulate what javascript does, but you need to re-do what the scripts are doing manually, so whether it's doable without Selenium depends on how much of JavaScript is needed to make the site work, and how much time you're ready to invest in it.